# Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'providerID' Firebase 5.0

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the newest version of FirebaseAuth 5.0
this is my code:

```
func registerUser (withEmail email: String, andPassword password: String, userCreationComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        guard let user = user else{
            userCreationComplete(false, error)
            return
        }
        let userData = ["provider": user.providerID, "email": user.email]
        DataService.instance.createDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
        userCreationComplete(true, nil)
    }

}
```

problem is "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no value "ProviderID" " But in firebase 4 this method worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#createuserwithemailpasswordcompletion), the `createUser` function passes a completion block with `(FIRAuthDataResult?, Error?)`. `FirAuthDataResult` is not the same as a `User`, but it has a `User` as a property, which can be accessed like this:

```
func registerUser (withEmail email: String, andPassword password: String, userCreationComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
        guard let user = authResult.user else {
            userCreationComplete(false, error)
            return
        }
        let userData = ["provider": user.providerID, "email": user.email]
        DataService.instance.createDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
        userCreationComplete(true, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot the optional reference in `guard let user = authResult?.user`

Answer (score 0):

```
func registerUser(withEmail email: String, andPassword password: String, userCreationComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
        guard let user = authResult?.user else {
            userCreationComplete(false, error)
            return
        }

        let userData = ["provider": user.providerID, "email": user.email]
        DataService.instance.createDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
        userCreationComplete(true, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).