# Cannot convert value of type '(User?, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(User?, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<AuthDataResult>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>')

at the 7th line of this code:

```
func handleRegister() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }

        //successfully authenticated user
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).jpg")

        if let profileImage = self.profileImageView.image, let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {

//            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                    let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409307/firebase-swift-4-authdataresult-eror/51409688#51409688 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589895/value-of-type-authdataresult-has-no-member-providerid-firebase-5-0/51600266#51600266

Comment: Remove the parentheses around `user, error`, this should fix the problem.